# Curious behavior of async/await

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, async-await, google-chrome-devtools

I know the proper way to use `await` is wrapping it up with `async` function.

I found this below approach while surfing online. Initially, I thought it will not work. But when I run this in my chrome console it surprises me. It works.

```
var _response = await (await fetch('https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2').then(res => res.json()));
console.log(_response);
```

But when I tried this approach in my Rectjs project it doesn't work.

Throws me below error.

> unknown: Unexpected token (1:22)
>
> > 1 | var _response = await (await fetch('https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2').then(res => res.json()));

I have also tried in a lot of online es6 compilers such as https://repl.it/languages/babel It won't work. It only works in my chrome console (chrome 74).

Someone help me out to understand this behavior clearly.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean "doesn't work"? You get an error? If so, what is it? Or is the `_response` just undefined?

Comment: What do you mean, `doesn't work`? Please post a [MCVE]

Comment: It's because only chrome implements top level await. If you run this code inside of an async function it should be fine

Comment: It should really be run inside (e.g.) an `async` IIFE.

Comment: "it doesn't work" is not a precise enough error description for us to help you. *What* doesn't work? *How* doesn't it work? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ?

Comment: I'm sorry for blankly specifying "it doesn't work". I have updated the code with the error message.

Comment: Like @AsafAviv said, an `async function` is required. See [MDN's async function documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) for more info

Comment: Guys, I know async is required for this. But why this code works in chrome console without async.?

Comment: chrome is the only browser that let you use await outside of an async function.

Answer (score 4):

The behavior you describe is specific to Chrome's DevTools.

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=658558

It looks like they added it in response to a feature request from the community.

Comment: Correct, this is just a convenience provided by DevTools. We call it [top-level await](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/08/devtools-release-notes#await).

Answer (score -1):

You can wrap you async call in an async IIFE like this:

```js
(async () => {
   var _response =  await fetch('https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2').then(res => res.json());
   console.log(_response);
})()
```

Comment: Thank for the answer. But unfortunately, I already knew this. 
I know how to make it work. I'm asking why this code works in console, not in es6?